# How to apply a function to a list with different aguments, from a different list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda, functional-programming

I have a list/generator of arguments that I need to put into a function to apply it in a list. The thing is that I'm practicing functional programming and want to avoid the use of 'for loops' except inside liste comprehensions (or generators, dicts , etc).

I have a list of arguments and each argument corresponds to a unique element in a different list, and I have a function to work those arguments and I want it to return a list.

I'm already having trouble explaining it.

```
args = [a,b,c,...]
function = funct()
elements [cc,vv,dg,...]
```

the function has to run with args[i] over elements[i] for each i (both lists have the same number of elements) but I don't need the combinations, just the one to one relation.

Comment: So the `function` takes two arguments?

Comment: Are you looking for `[funct(x, y) for x, y in zip(args, elements)]`?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more: "the function has to run with args[i] over elements[i] for each i" ? Is it just a zip ??

Comment: I'm think OP is just looking for zip

Comment: Why can't you use `map(func, args, elements)`? Or `[*map(func, args, elements)]` if you want the output in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

You can use `zip()` to do what you want. From the `documentation`:

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

So to give an example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8)]
```

As `zip()` returns an `iterator`, you can iterate over the tuples without the need for the `list()` call as in the example. This can be done in a `list-comprehension` where we unpack each `tuple` into the variables `a` and `b` and then pass these into your function `funct()` one by one:

```
[funct(a, b) for a, b in zip(args, elements)]
```